# Unit's digit of exponential factorial

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

$$\boxed{\text{Define } n!! \overset{\text {def}}{=} n^{{(n-1)}^{{(n-2)}^{{{{\text{.}}^{\text{.}}}^1}}}} \text { for } n\in \mathbb{N}}$$

Find, with proof, all possible units digit of $n!!$ for $n\geq 1$

Pattern hunting (the unit's digit) or considering the repeat cycle of the unit's digit doesn't seem feasible in this case. Also, another way is to check $n$ modulo $5$ (and considering the parity of $n$) but that's quite strenuous and doesn't look good.

Am I missing something? Any hint or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: The remainder of $n^k$ modulo $10$ is determined by the remainder of $n$ modulo $10$ and the remainder of $k$ modulo $4$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I am aware of that. As I said, the cyclic repetition checking makes a big solution.

Comment: So you have to look at $(n-1)^{(n-2)\cdots}\pmod 4$, and since $\varphi(4)=2$ you look at $(n-2)^{(n-3)\cdots}\pmod{2}$ so if $n$ is even you get $(n-1)^{(n-2)\cdots}\equiv 0\pmod 4$ so $n^{(n-1)\cdots}\equiv n\pmod{10}$ if $n$ is even (unless I made a mistake).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overestimating the pattern checking required.  For example, if $n\equiv 0 \pmod {10}, n!! \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$ and we are done.  If $n \equiv 9 \pmod {10}$ the exponent is even and $n!! \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$.  The powers of each digit go through a cycle of at most $4$ when considered $\bmod 10$.  For $2$ the power is always odd, so the only possibilities are $2,8$.  We can see $2!!=2,$ so $2$ is possible.  It is possible that the exponent is $3 \bmod 4$ when the last digit of $n$ is $2?$.  Just do it and see where you run into problems.